# How to compare jmeter graphs of multiple test cycles efficiently?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I created an automated jmeter test which gives me these nice reports:

[image: Jmeter result graph]
The test is executed every day. If I want to compare two cycles, then I need to open two charts and compare them, but I would like to see the graphs of both test cycles in one chart overlapped. Whats the best practice to achieve that? My jmeter test also creates a result xml file which should contain all the required information. Should I import that to other plotting software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin which can be used for combining 2 or more .jtl results files, you can give them different prefixes and plot them onto one chart:

   [image]
2. There is [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) cloud analysis service which basically does the same, but in the fancy web interface
3. You can also put your JMeter test under [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), for example using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/). Jenkins has [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) which adds execution results to the build dashboard and you will also have [Performance Trend](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html) charts showing your application performance metrics compared from run to run

   [image]